# Rails methods that can work with multiple tables and column names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-2.0

hope you are all well!

I have a general enquiry that I was wondering if some kind soul could help with? it's really a matter of curiosity at the minute but I feel like it could be quite a useful snippet of information in the future.

Is it possible to write a method that can be passed the name of a table and the name of an attribute (column) and perform operations on these? I suppose the main use for such methods would be for keeping code dry when doing repetitive operations on tables.

as an example (though entirely a toy example) suppose I had a method:

```
def switch(table_name, column_name)
    #do some operation on table_name.column_name
end
```

I have figured out how to access a table by doing something like this:

```
def model_for_table(table_name) 
    table_name.to_s.classify.constantize 
end
```

this will take an underscored_lowercase_string and return the table name so that something like `model_for_table("registered_user").find(1)` though this is unnecessary in situations where the table name can be hard coded

But it does not like `model_for_table("registered_user").column_name` as used in the example above. is there something analogous to the `model_for_table` method supplied above to turn a string into an attribute name?

Does anybody know how I could implement this? is it even possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be useful to know what you're trying to do. Rails  is object oriented so in general you shouldn't need to worry about your tables - just work with objects instead. If you know all that and really need to manipulate your tables directly then carry on!

Comment: The thought came to me the other day whilst coding some house keeping for some HABTM associations, I foresaw that I would probably need to do it again at some point in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need an instance of the model you are working on in order to access a column. If you have a RegisteredUser model try doing (in a Rails console) `RegisteredUser.id` (or any attribute name). It won't work. However, if you did `RegisteredUser.first.id` (assuming you have one saved) it will work.

So it depends on what you want to accomplish. If your `switch` method is meant to do something with instances of your model, then this can still work.

```
def switch(table_name, column_name)
  model = model_for_table(table_name)
  model.all.each do |model_instance|
    puts "model_instance #{column_name} is #{model_instance.send(column_name)}"
  end
end
```

Note: The `send` method takes in a symbol or a String and executes the method with that name on the instance it was called on. This is a normal Ruby thing, not a Rails thing.

Remember, your `model_for_table` method is returning back the class, not an instance.

Comment: That's the bunny! Thanks a lot, As I said in the comment above, the idea came to me whilst coding some house keeping for some HABTM associations, as there will be a few tables with them, it would have been nice to encapsulate the code in a method rather than repeat very similar code throughout the application. Thank you very much for your time

Comment: No worries! I do love DRY code, but just be wary if it gets to use too much meta code that it gets confusing

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, but for this purpose, it's really just iterating through a table to find any HABTMs that aren't associated, it just happens that there are a few tables I want to find the unassociated relations for, each one has a different table name and association name. Like I said though, there are a few uses I have for this now I know how to use it